# Python, convert coordinate degrees to decimal points

Tags: python, geolocation, coordinates

I have a list of latitude and longitude as follows:

```
['33.0595° N', '101.0528° W']
```

I need to convert it to floats `[33.0595, -101.0528]`.

Sure, the '-' is the only difference, but it changes when changing hemispheres, which is why a library would be ideal, but I can't find one.

Comment: what do you mean by *change when changing hemispheres* ? can you add an example for each case ?

Comment: the example above is in the US... in new zealand for example, it would be -44.079796, 170.178351.. so the '-' switches to the longitude value.

Comment: Maybe you should understand the meaning of both notations, and so you may also write down easily the code. Doing it manually (it is easy) it helps you to give users better errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the following code in a function and use it:

```
import re

l = ['33.0595° N', '101.0528° W']
new_l = []
for e in l:
    num = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", e)
    if e[-1] in ["W", "S"]:
        new_l.append(-1. * float(num[0]))
    else:
        new_l.append(float(num[0]))

print(new_l)  # [33.0595, -101.0528]
```

The result match what you expect.

Comment: You need to also account for 'S' in the North-South coordinate.

Comment: @AhtoTruu Thanks, I edited the answer to contain both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the way I would solve the issue. I think the previous answer uses regex that might prove to be a bit slower (would need benchmarking).

```py
data = ["33.0595° N", "101.0528° W"]


def convert(coord):
    val, direction = coord.split(" ") # split the direction and the value
    val = float(val[:-1]) # turn the value (without the degree symbol) into float
    return val if direction not in ["W", "S"] else -1 * val # return val if the direction is not West


converted = [convert(coord) for coord in data] # [33.0595, -101.0528]
```

Comment: This also negates the "N", which should remain positive.

Comment: It only negates the values that are W or S. if you see the result at the end the North coordinate is positive.

Comment: Now better indeed :)